# Date panel not aligned to the date control in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular` and `Angular Material` to display date control

The code is below..

```
<input type="date" (change)="validateDateRange($event,true, index)"  class="form-control oot-start-date align-middle" name="from" formControlName="startDate" />

.oot-start-date {
    width: 170px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.align-middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

With these current settings, it displays the calendar control as below...

[image: Calendar Control]

How to align it's panel properly to the date control?

Comment: did your previous issue resolve?

Comment: The previous question is not yet resolved.

Comment: I would like to align the calendar panel to the center horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using native date picker you can just set the width to the width of the popup, why I suggest this is because we need to style the date picker based on the browsers, which is just extra complexity for a simple issue!

We can also remove the other CSS you have added related to positioning!

```
<div class="center">
  <input type="date" value="2006-01-01" style="width: 215px" />
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/iuvb3p?file=src%2Fexample%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html)